# C# Random class strange errors

Tags: c#, random

```
namespace RandomBug
{
    class Program
    {
        static Random rnd = new Random(0);
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {           
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
                Program.rnd.Next(100);                        
        }
    }
}
```

This code gives me all kind of strange inner errors like:  Null Access, Array out of range, etc.
This not happen if the Random is not static. I'm using VS 2015.
I found this problem after I saw bad random results on C# Unity.

Comment: So to be clear, are you seeing the problem in this regular console app (and if so, which framework version are you targeting?) or is it only in Unity? (I can't reproduce it with the code you've shown.)

Comment: I'm always using static randoms and have never seen such errors. http://ideone.com/AqdD0b - everything is ok.

Comment: Ary you sure you don't use your own `Random` class?

Comment: This happens after a few trials in regular console app.

Comment: You sure about the unity3d tag? This cannot be done in Unity as you cannot use the Main method. I guess this is most likely unity not 3d isn't it?

Comment: IF you are using Unity, use `Random.Range`.  Look in the manual.

Comment: Perhaps the memory of your computer is starting to fail?

Comment: I'm realize no one seeing this problem except me....
This is also a way for solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is a default unity feature that works as well:

```
namespace RandomBug
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {           
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
                Random.Range(0,100);                       
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sometimes you need more than one Random class.